# Templates: template function not playing well with class's template member function

Tags: c++, templates

This is a minimal test case of some code that I actually have. It fails when it tries to evaluate `a.getResult<B>()`:

```
test.cpp: In function 'void printStuff(const A&)':
test.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
test.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

template< class A, class B>
void printStuff( const A& a)
{
    size_t value = a.getResult<B>();
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

struct Firstclass {
    template< class X >
    size_t getResult() const {
        X someInstance;
        return sizeof(someInstance);
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Firstclass foo;

    printStuff<Firstclass, short int>(foo);
    printStuff<Firstclass, double>(foo);

    std::cout << foo.getResult< double >() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the `printStuff` function and where it's called, the `foo.getResult< double >()` call compiles fine and does what is expected.

Any idea what's going on? I've been working with extensively templated code for a while and have never encountered anything like this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When you refer to a template that is a member of dependent type, you have to prepend it with a keyword `template`. This is how the call to `getResult` inside `printStuff` should look

```
size_t value = a.template getResult<B>();
```

This is similar to using the keyword `typename` when referring to nested typenames in a dependent type. For some reason, the bit about `typename` with nested types is rather well-known, but the similar requirement for `template` with nested templates is relatively unknown.

Note that the general syntax structure is a bit different though. The `typename` is always put in front of the full name of the type, while `template` is inserted in the middle.

Again, this is only necessary when you are accessing a template member of a *dependent type*, which in the above example would be `A` in `printStuff`. When you call `foo.getResult<>` in `main` the type of `foo` is not dependent, so there's no need to include the `template` keyword.

Comment: Thanks! That's the most bizarre syntax I've ever seen in C++.

Comment: Somehow VC++ is quite lenient about it (ie, you can often get away without it), but gcc is definitely not!

Comment: Totally agree with you guys on all three points, except I found gcc to also be lenient until cross-compiling for ARM with CodeSourcery.

Comment: wow, I thought I knew everything about C++ syntax as well; I've co-written a C++ front-end and I didn't know this

Comment: Good if the error message produced by GCC could be a little bit descriptive about the missing keyword. Even with GCC10 if i forget the template keyword, I receive 'error: expected primary-expression before '>' token', which does not help in any way... if it could be something like 'expecting 'template' before a templated function call'

Answer (score 10):

Your code is ill-formed according to C++ Standard 14.2/4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression*, or after *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

So, you should write `size_t value = a.template getResult<B>();`