# C++ template gotchas

Tags: c++, templates

just now I had to dig through the website to find out why template class template member function was giving syntax errors:

```
template<class C> class F00 {
   template<typename T> bar();
};
...
Foo<C> f;
f.bar<T>(); // syntax error here
```

I now realize that template brackets are treated as relational operators.  To do what was intended the following bizarre syntax is needed, cf [Templates: template function not playing well with class's template member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682844/templates-template-function-not-playing-well-with-classs-template-member-functi):

```
f.template bar<T>();
```

what other bizarre aspects and gotcha of C++/C++ templates you have encountered that were not something that you would consider to be common knowledge?

Comment: Btw, you might want to limit it to template gotchas only, there's already another question for general C++ gotchas.

Comment: What return type does `template<typename T> bar();` have?

Comment: You're mistaken in your assumption. You do NOT need `template` here, as `f` is not a dependent name. What would it depend on anyway? It's a name in an unspecified scope, for an object of type `Foo<C>`.

Answer (score 14):

I got tripped up the first time I inherited a templated class from another templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
    int a;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
    void func() {
        a++; // error! 'a' has not been declared
    }
};
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know if `Base<T>` is going to be the default template or a specialized one. A specialized version may not have `int a` as a member, so the compiler doesn't assume that it's available. But you can tell the compiler that it's going to be there with the `using` directive:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
    using Base<T>::a;
    void func() {
        a++; // OK!
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can make it explicit that you are using a member of `T`:

```
void func {
    T::a++; // OK!
}
```

Comment: "the compiler doesn't know if Base<T> is going to be the default template": that's a great explanation.  Note that using a base class member variable is _actually_ breaking encapsulation, hence discouraged.

Comment: The same problem exists for base class _methods_. The problem happens in name lookup, at which point you don't even know what you'll find.

Answer (score 8):

This one got me upset back then:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

struct foo {
  template<typename U>
  void vector();
};

int main() {
  foo f;
  f.vector<int>(); // ambiguous!
}
```

The last line in main is ambiguous, because the compiler not only looks up `vector` within `foo`, but also as an unqualified name starting from within `main`. So it finds both `std::vector` and `foo::vector`. To fix this, you have to write

```
f.foo::vector<int>();
```

GCC does not care about that, and accepts the above code by doing the intuitive thing (calling the member), other compilers do better and warn like comeau:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 13: warning: ambiguous class member reference -- function
          template "foo::vector" (declared at line 8) used in preference to
          class template "std::vector" (declared at line 163 of
          "stl_vector.h")
        f.vector<int>(); // ambiguous!
```

Comment: Is there a GCC flag to make it warn about this? (I bet there is, there are about a million of them...)

Comment: Huh? I don't understand how this could be ambiguous to the compiler. Anything after `f.` must be a member of `foo`, so why does it find `std::vector`? Is there any situation where you could want it to find a non-member?

Comment: @Peter it's got to do with arcane language situations. The rule that `vector` is looked up also in the surrounding scope doesn't exist anymore in C++0x. It also produces only warnings (if any message at all) on modern C++03 compilers. For example, [see here for clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#opt_Wambiguous-member-template). After a `f.`, the next name is not necessarily a member of `foo`. For example consider: `struct A { void f(); }; struct B { typedef A type; }; int main() { A a; a.B::type::f(); }`.

Answer (score 5):

The star of questions about templates here on SO: the missing typename!

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
  public:
    typedef T * iterator;
    ...
};

template <typename T>
void func()
{
    vector<T>::iterator it;           // this is not correct!

    typename vector<T>::iterator it2; // this is correct.
}
```

The problem here is that `vector<T>::iterator` is a dependent name: it depends on a template parameter. As a consequence, the compiler does not know that `iterator` designates a type; we need to tell him with the `typename` keyword.

The same goes for template inner classes or template member/static functions: they must be disambiguated using the `template` keyword, as noted in the OP.

```
template <typename T>
void func()
{
    T::staticTemplateFunc<int>();          // ambiguous

    T::template staticTemplateFunc<int>(); // ok

    T t;

    t.memberTemplateFunc<int>();          // ambiguous

    t.template memberTemplateFunc<int>(); // ok
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Out of scope class member function definition:

```
template <typename T> 
class List {                     // a namespace scope class template 
  public: 
    template <typename T2>       // a member function template 
    List (List<T2> const&);      // (constructor) 
    … 
}; 
template <typename T> 
 template <typename T2> 
List<T>::List (List<T2> const& b) // an out-of-class member function 
{                                 // template definition 
    … 
}
```