# Strange GCC 'expected primary expression...' error

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Templates: template function not playing well with class’s template member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682844/templates-template-function-not-playing-well-with-classs-template-member-functi)

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <int I>
    void f();
};

template <typename T>
void F(A<T> &a)
{
    a.f<0>(); // expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
}

int main()
{
    A<int> a;

    a.f<0>(); // This one is ok.
}
```

What it's all about?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a *dependent* name is used to refer to a nested template, the nested name has to be prepended with the keyword `template` to help the compiler understand that you are referring to a nested template and parse the code correctly

```
template <typename T>
void F(A<T> &a)
{
    a.template f<0>();
}
```

Inside `main` the name `a` is not dependent, which is why you don't need the extra `template` keyword. Inside `F` name `a` is dependent, which is why the keyword is needed.

This is similar to the extra `typename` keyword when referring to nested type names through a dependent name. Just the syntax is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

In the former, the compiler thinks that you mean...

```
a.f < 0 ...gibberish....
```

Andrey's answer fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there *are* code snippet that are valid for *both* the keyword added and *not* added, yielding different results in each case, even for templates that take type parameters instead of integers.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { 
  template<typename T> 
  static A f(T) { 
    return A(); 
  } 

  template<typename T> operator T() { return T(); }
}; 

template<typename U> 
int g() { 
  U u;
  typedef A (*funcPtrType)(int());
  return !(funcPtrType)u.f < int() > (0); 
}

int main() {
  std::cout << g<A>() << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs `0` when run without the `template` keyword added. If you add the keyword before `f < int() >` it outputs `1`.

---

**Explanation**

The version without the keyword parses as

```
funcPtrType temp1 = (funcPtrType)u.f; // taking func address
bool temp2 = !temp1;                  // temp2 == false
bool temp3 = temp2 < int();           // temp3 == false
bool temp4 = temp3 > (0);             // temp4 == false
return temp4;
```

And the version with the keyword parses as

```
A temp1 = u.template f < int() > (0);     // function call
funcPtrType temp2 = (funcPtrType) temp1;  // temp2 == 0
bool temp3 = !temp2;                      // temp3 == true
return temp3;
```

Notice that `temp2` is a null pointer (produced by `return T()`). Whole different parses, and both are valid! This really needs a way to disambiguate - which is to insert the `template` keyword as appropriate.