# C++ template compilation error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, boost, compiler-errors

This code compiles and works as expected (it throws at runtime, but never mind):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

void foo(boost::property_tree::ptree &pt) 
{
    std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("path"); // <---
}

int main()
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    foo(pt);
    return 0;
}
```

But as soon as I add templates and change the `foo` prototype into

```
template<class ptree>
void foo(ptree &pt)
```

I get an error in GCC:

```
test_ptree.cpp: In function ‘void foo(ptree&)’:
test_ptree.cpp:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
```

but no errors with MSVC++! The error is in the marked line `<---`. And again, if I change the problem line into

```
--- std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("path"); // <---
+++ std::cout << pt.get("path", "default value");
```

the error disappears (the problem is in explicit `<std::string>`).

[Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) requires Boost >= 1.41. Please help me to understand and fix this error.

---

**See [Templates: template function not playing well with class’s template member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682844/templates-template-function-not-playing-well-with-classs-template-member-functi)** — a similar popular question containing other good answers and explanations.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682844/templates-template-function-not-playing-well-with-classs-template-member-functi/1682885 (Duplicate?)

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Templates: template function not playing well with class's template member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682844/templates-template-function-not-playing-well-with-classs-template-member-funct)

Comment: Sorry to excavate this, but if you say that this is a duplicate, it should be marked as such IMHO :)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to do:

```
std::cout << pt.template get<std::string>("path");
```

Use `template` in the same situation as `typename`, except for template members instead of types.

(That is, since `pt::get` is a template member *dependent* on a template parameter, you need to tell the compiler it's a template.)

Comment: Nice.  Do you have a specific resource you use for template usage?  I ask out of curiosity.  None of my books seemed to address this issue.

Comment: @Chance: I don't, sadly, though you might find one off [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), namely *C++ Templates, The Complete Guide*.

Comment: Why do you need to tell the compiler it's a template? Shouldn't the compiler be able to figure that out by itself?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: I don't remember if it's theoretically possible in C++ for the compiler to always deduce it correctly, probably not. The problem is that without `template`, it could be parsed as `(pt.get) < std::string > ("path");`, that is comparisons. In this case, comparisons for type names isn't possible so it could figure out, but in general how would you parse `pt.val < 5 > (10)`? Adding `template` tells the compiler directly "this is a function call".

Comment: Ah, okay, so it is the old incompatibility problem with comparison operators and template notation again... :P Well, that makes sense. I guess the D programming language has the upper hand here with its `(...)` template syntax instead of C++' `<...>` syntax :)