# Pass class with templated method as template parameter with GCC

Tags: c++, function, templates

Is it possible to pass object of a class with templated method as a template parameter under GCC? All search I conducted pointed me to questions regarding templated class, which is not applicable in my case.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void print(const T& arg) const
    {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename A>
void print(const A& printer)
{
    printer.print<int>(1);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    print<Foo>(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling under MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1 I get the following results:

```
tmpl.cpp: In function 'void print(const A&)':
tmpl.cpp:16:19: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     printer.print<int>(1);
                   ^~~
tmpl.cpp:16:19: error: expected ';' before 'int'
```

VisualStudio compiles the same code cleanly, application works as expected. If I make `print` function not templated, so that is explicitly takes object of `Foo` it works as expected both compilers.

Comment: Interesting to see duplicates 4 times upvote. Is a criteria for upvote that there was own research ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`template`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) keyword to tell that `print` is a template.

> Inside a template definition, `template` can be used to declare that a dependent name is a template.

e.g.

```
template<typename A>
void print(const A& printer)
{
    printer.template print<int>(1);
    //      ~~~~~~~~
}
```

`print` is a dependent name, it depends on the template parameter `A`. Before the template gets instantiated the compiler knows nothing about `A`; so you need to add the `template` keyword to tell the compiler that `print` is a template, then the `<` after the name `print` is valid; otherwise `<` will be treated as the `operator<` then cause the error.

Comment: Admittedly, I find this syntax quite confusing....

Comment: @lubgr I added some explanations, hope could help you to understand it..

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is clear and I understand why the keyword is needed at this point. It's just being so used to a member variable/function after the dot, and in particular no spaces between instance and member var./fct. (even though there could be).

Comment: @lubgr You'll get used to it; it's quite a common issue in c++ templates.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both answers are correct, but I marked your as more thorough :)

Answer (score 3):

You need the `template` keyword in order to specify that `print()` is a template, like this:

```
printer.template print<int>(1);
```

Comment: @Klaus I wanted to check it first in the compiler. However I see that the other answer was edited, which makes it a bit different. :) 
I saw the duplicate, you are right, marked that! ;)

Comment: It was only for fun! And it is also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505713/c-template-compilation-error-expected-primary-expression-before-token

Comment: Thanks for the help :) It would seem that my google-fu needs a level-up, as I failed to locate that question :) Indeed it is a duplicate, with the possible difference that my title fits a different combination of keywords :)

Comment: @DarthHunterix we all have been in this situation! =) Thanks for the nice question, deserved my upvote. You did well to accept the other answer, since after its edit, it's more complete than mine.