# CUDA device array implementation using templates

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I am trying to implement a fixed-size version of Thrust's device vector. I coded some initial version but I am getting a curious template error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

enum class memcpy_t {
    host_to_host,
    host_to_device,
    device_to_host,
    device_to_device
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct cuda_allocator {
    using pointer = T*;

    static void allocate(T *dev_mem) {
        cudaMalloc(&dev_mem, N * sizeof(T)); 
    }

    static void deallocate(T *dev_mem) {
        cudaFree(dev_mem); 
    }

    template <memcpy_t ct>
    static void copy (T *dst, T *src) {
        switch(ct) {
        case memcpy_t::host_to_host:
            cudaMemcpy(dst, src, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToHost);
            break;
        case memcpy_t::host_to_device:
            cudaMemcpy(dst, src, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            break;
        case memcpy_t::device_to_host:
            cudaMemcpy(dst, src, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            break;
        case memcpy_t::device_to_device:
            cudaMemcpy(dst, src, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct gpu_array {
    using allocator = cuda_allocator<T, N>;
    using pointer = typename allocator::pointer;
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = T const*;

    gpu_array() {
        allocator::allocate(data);
    }

    gpu_array(std::array<T, N> host_arr) {
        allocator::allocate(data);
        allocator::copy<memcpy_t::host_to_device>(data, host_arr.begin());
    }

    gpu_array& operator=(gpu_array const& o) {
        allocator::allocate(data);
        allocator::copy<memcpy_t::device_to_device>(data, o.begin());
    }

    operator std::array<T, N>() {
        std::array<T, N> res;
        allocator::copy<memcpy_t::device_to_host>(res.begin(), data);
        return res;
    }

    ~gpu_array() {
        allocator::deallocate(data);
    }

    __device__ iterator begin() { return data; }
    __device__ iterator end() { return data + N; }
    __device__ const_iterator begin() const { return data; }
    __device__ const_iterator end() const { return data + N; }

private:
    T* data;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
__global__ void add_kernel(gpu_array<T,N> &r,
                           gpu_array<T,N> const&a1,
                           gpu_array<T,N> const&a2) {
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    r.begin()[i] = a1.begin()[i] + a2.begin()[i];
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
gpu_array<T, N> operator+(gpu_array<T,N> const&a1,
                          gpu_array<T,N> const&a2)
{
    gpu_array<T, N> res;
    add_kernel<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(res, a1, a2);
    return res;
}

const int N = 1<<20;

int main() {
    std::array<float, N> x,y;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    } 

    gpu_array<float, N> dx{x};
    gpu_array<float, N> dy{y};

    std::array<float, N> res = dx + dy;

    for(const auto& elem : res) {
        std::cout << elem << ", ";
    }
}
```

There might be tons of other errors but I am stuck at a curious one. `nvcc` gives me the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are '<unresolved overloaded function    type>' and 'memcpy_t')
allocator::copy<memcpy_t::host_to_device>(data, host_arr.begin());
```

For some reason, does it see my enum class template parameter as `operator<`? By the way, this is compiled with options `-arch=sm_70 -std=c++14`. I am not well-educated on how C++ and CUDA interacts so I could not solve the problem.

Comment: Just an observation -- that error is being generated by g++ not nvcc, and if you strip all the CUDA device code out of your MCVE and then include the CUDA runtime headers and compile directly with g++ you will see the same thing. What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: `gcc` version is 5.4.0. It should support C++11. Maybe enum classes as template parameters are not viable in this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a bit of head scratching, but the underlying problem here is defective syntax according to the C++ standard. It is the host compiler generating the error, and it is perfectly correct for it to do so, as far as I can see. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682844/681865) for all the gory details.

Your code which uses the specializations of `copy` should look like this:

```
gpu_array(std::array<T, N> host_arr) {
    allocator::allocate(data);
    allocator::template copy<memcpy_t::host_to_device>(data, host_arr.begin());
}

gpu_array& operator=(gpu_array const& o) {
    allocator::allocate(data);
    allocator::template copy<memcpy_t::device_to_device>(data, o.begin());
}

operator std::array<T, N>() {
    std::array<T, N> res;
    allocator::template copy<memcpy_t::device_to_host>(res.begin(), data);
    return res;
}
```

That might be the strangest looking syntax ever, but it is what is required to make the compiler honor `<` as a template token and not an operator. Fix that everywhere in your code and this particular compiler error should disappear.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Now, I am getting seg fault which is nice. This makes interface of my allocator very ugly tough. I could change it to use tag parameters instead.

Comment: The segfault is probably due to that huge std::array on the stack. Make N something more sensible